# wildcards in php for email check function

Tags: php, email, wildcard

i am currently developing login and register system on my local machine for test purposes and, now, i am in phase of email checking function. as you know, you can use php build in function for that, that is not 100% correct. otherway, i want that only @gmail.com , @hotmail.* , @yahoo.* and emails like that to be accepted, not others (i.e. @somemail.net).

so i want to develop code that should look like:

```
    <?

    ...

    require_once 'emailformcheck.php';

    if ($email === '@gmail.com' || $email === '@yahoo.com'...) {

        require_once 'emaildbcheck.php';

        require_once 'passwordchecker.php';

}

...

?>
```

but instead of typing @gmail.com or @yahoo.* , i want to use some wild cards instead of that, like:

*@gmail.com or *@yahoo.com . can anybody tell me how i need to format that, true is, i am not really new in php programming but i still learn. anybody knows some wildcard for replacing string data in php file?

Comment: You are looking for `regular expressions` and the preg extension in php. They implement pattern search in strings. Read the documentation, this is well described and has been answered a million times.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why would one limit a registration/login by the email service provider potential users chose?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First run this function to check if the email is valid:

```
$isValid = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

Then to check the domain run the following:

```
list ($user, $domain) = explode('@', $email);
list ($domain, $tld) = explode('.', $domain);
```

Where $user conains the data before the @, domain contains the domain excluding the TLD (e.g. `gmail`) and $tld contains the first part of the TLD (e.g. `com`).

You can then check for gmail.com with this condition:

```
if($domain == "gmail" && $tld == "com")
```

and to check for wildcards like hotmail use:

```
if($domain == "hotmail")
```

Clearly using wildcards you are going to run into subdomain problems such as someone making a domain: `hotmail.mywebsite.com` and their email being `myname@hotmail.mywebsite.com`.

Comment: wow, thanks. yes, this can be something that i look for. few edits and can be great in the end. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Use `regular expressions` for such pattern search in strings. PHP brings the `preg` extension. It is well documented, so I suggest you take a look at the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-match.php) and the millions of examples you find on the web:

Using that you can write your conditional as something like:

```
if ( preg_match($email, '^[^@]+@((gmail\.com)|(yahoo\.com))$') )
```